# Module not found: Can't resolve '@sanity/client' and '@sanity/image-url'

Tags: model, syntax-error, sanity

```
import sanityClient  from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: "7c4vy8nu",
  dataset: "production",
  useCdn: true,
  apiVersion: "2021-10-21",
});
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
// sanity cors add https://localhost:19000
export default client;
```

Unable to resolve module @sanity/client from D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\sanity.js: @sanity/client could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules ....\node_modules ......\node_modules 1 | import sanityClient  from "@sanity/client"; |                            ^ 2 | import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url"; 3 | 4 | const client = sanityClient({ at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:162:15) at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:260:43) at Object.resolve (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:177:21) at Graph._resolveDependencies (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:432:35) at Graph._processModule (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:218:38) at async Graph._addDependency (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:314:20) at async Promise.all (index 0) at async Graph._processModule (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:263:5) at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:207:5) at async Graph.traverseDependencies (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:147:9) at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:247:42) at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:90:16) at async DeltaBundler.getDelta (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler.js:67:12) at async IncrementalBundler.updateGraph (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:218:19) at async Server._explodedSourceMapForURL (D:\code\Introduce about mobile devolopment\ReactBasic-1\New folder\Project1\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1135:23) at async Promise.all (index 0)

- And i have also install

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@sanity/client": "^5.3.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
  },
```

I really appreciate if anyone can help me

```
type here
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I had and the solution that worked for me was sanityClient is deprecated and replaced with {createClient} try using this code snippet.

Install these packages and then try to use below code.

```js
npm install -g @sanity/client
npm install -g @sanity/image-url
```

```js
import {createClient} from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = createClient({
  projectId: 'Add-your-project-id-here',
  dataset: 'Add-your-dataset-name-here',
  useCdn: true,
  apiVersion: '2023-05-03',
})

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client)
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source)

export async function getPosts() {
  const posts = await client.fetch('*[_type == "post"]')
  return posts
}

export async function createPost(post: Post) {
  const result = client.create(post)
  return result
}

export async function updateDocumentTitle(_id, title) {
  const result = client.patch(_id).set({title})
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import {createClient} from '@sanity/client'

try installing with force

npm i @sanity/client --force
npm instal @sanity/image-url --force

mostly this helps

or install it using -g tag for global installation
like the other answer